# Set value of a select in IE using YUI3

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, yui3

I have a select box and I need to both set the selected value and issue a change event with javascript.

In Firefox, the following works with no problem:

```
Y.one('#my_select_box').set('value', STEP_VALUES);
Y.one('#my_select_box').simulate('change');
```

No such luck in IE (IE7 in this case).  The selected's value does not even change.  I have tried using 'selectedIndex' instead of 'value' too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable answer is `mySelect.query('option[value=foo]').set('selected', true);`, however according [this ticket](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/ticket/2528084) it looks like the `set('value', value)` approach should work on the select tag itself, so I'm still unsure about that (I'm using YUI 3.1.1), so I'm still interested in any comments.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have success with the suggested answer, however I did have success with.

```
Y.one("#object").set("selectedIndex", 1);
```

Where 1 is the index to be selected.